# java android app execute every 10 seconds

Tags: java, android

I have this code, for a android app i'm working on:

```
package com.exercise.AndroidInternetTxt;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidInternetTxt extends Activity {

    TextView textMsg, textPrompt, textSite;
    final String textSource = "http://www.xxx/s.php";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        textPrompt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textprompt);
        textMsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textmsg);
        textSite = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textsite);

        //textPrompt.setText("Asteapta...");


        URL textUrl;
        try {
            textUrl = new URL(textSource);
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream()));
            String StringBuffer;
            String stringText = "";
            while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringText += StringBuffer;
            }
            bufferReader.close();
            textMsg.setText(stringText);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            textMsg.setText(e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            textMsg.setText(e.toString());
        }


        //textPrompt.setText("Terminat!");

    }

}
```

It works fine, it outputs a text from the .php file. I would like it to autorefresh every 10 seconds, but sincerely  i don`t know how to do that. Can you please help me solve this out? Thanks!

Comment: Be careful! You need to create a new thread and do your heavy work there. Don't pause the `onCreate()` method, or else your program won't start up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A timer task will not work, as it will create a different thread and only originating thread may touch its views.

For android the preferred way to do this is to use a handler. Ether by

```
textMsg.post( new Runnable(){

     public void run(){
            doProcessing();
            testMesg.setText("bla");
            testMsg.postDelayed(this,(1000*10));
     }
};
```

or having a seperate instance of the Handler class

```
Handler mHanlder = new Handler();
mHandler.post(runnable);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should have been answered plenty of times before here.Here is how I would do it.

```
TimerTask fileProcessTask = new TimerTask(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //put your code to process the url here  
            processFile();

        }

    };

        Timer tm = new Timer();
        tm.schedule(fileProcessTask, 10000L);
```

Should work