# setText during a countdown

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a problem I can't set the text of a button during a countdown, this is the code:

```
begin.setText("Start level 1");
begin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View arg0) {

final int delay = 0000; // delay for 5 sec.
final int period = 1000; // repeat every sec.
final Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    public  void run() {
        begin.setText("" + t);
        t--;
        if(t == 0) {
            timer.cancel()
        }
    }
}, delay, period);
```

this is the logcat:

```
android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
07-30 17:27:05.273: E/AndroidRuntime(22543):    at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2802)
07-30 17:27:05.273: E/AndroidRuntime(22543):    at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:594)
07-30 17:27:05.273: E/AndroidRuntime(22543):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8128)
07-30 17:27:05.273: E/AndroidRuntime(22543):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8128)
07-30 17:27:05.273: E/AndroidRuntime(22543):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8128)
07-30 17:27:05.273: E/AndroidRuntime(22543):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:254)
07-30 17:27:05.273: E/AndroidRuntime(22543):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8128)
07-30 17:27:05.273: E/AndroidRuntime(22543):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8128)
07-30 17:27:05.273: E/AndroidRuntime(22543):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:5405)
07-30 17:27:05.273: E/AndroidRuntime(22543):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2712)
07-30 17:27:05.273: E/AndroidRuntime(22543):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2580)
07-30 17:27:05.273: E/AndroidRuntime(22543):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2555)
07-30 17:27:05.273: E/AndroidRuntime(22543):    at it.bisemanuDEV.piano.livello1$1$1.run(livello1.java:134)
07-30 17:27:05.273: E/AndroidRuntime(22543):    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:289)
```

I hope you can help.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272335/how-to-change-button-text-dynamically-for-every-3-sec-in-android

Comment: Use something similar to this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742944/java-android-app-execute-every-10-seconds/10744482#10744482

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Jug6ernaut mentioned, you shouldn't use a `TimerTask`.
Instead, you could try using a `Handler`.  This is how I do things like that in a timer.

For example, in your timer when you want to call `.setText()`, do this:

```
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        begin.setText(gcalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+gcalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));   
    }
});
```

It is initialized simply as `Handler mHandler = new Handler()`.

**Edit:** Just noticed this is the same idea as the other SO question links posted in the comments below your answer... well, here it is anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`TimerTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) instead of this. According to the documentation, `The TimerTask class represents a task to run at a specified time. The task may be run once or repeatedly`. Exactly what you are looking for. Example of using a `TimerTask` can be found [here](http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/18/scheduling-a-timer-task-to-run-repeatedly/).

Comment: yup, @bicska88, you are right, +1 for you. But, don't you think that this should be a comment.!!

Comment: Android documents specifically state to not use timertasks. Plus a TimerTask creates a new thread and as such will not be able to interact with Views from the UI thread.

Comment: UI manipulation depends on the implementation. Please provide Android documents that specifically state not to use `TimerTasks`.